# CGImageSourceCreateImageAtIndex always returns CGImage in Up orientation?

Tags: ios

I thought `CGImageSourceCreateImageAtIndex` returns `CGImage` in orientation determined by `kCGImagePropertyOrientation` property of result of `CGImageSourceCopyPropertiesAtIndex`. However in reality I find it always returns `CGImage` in Up orientation. Is it said anywhere in Apple's documentation?